# PHP mensagem do e-mail em UTF-8

Tags: php, email

Estou tentando fazer uma `form` capaz de enviar um e-mail e estou com um problema para entender como por a mensagem do e-mail em UTF-8, o que eu consegui fazer tranquilamente com o assunto do e-mail, mas não com a mensagem.

Segue abaixo o código do PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode("$subject").'?=';

    $mailTo = "email@email.com.br";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "Foi recebida uma nova mensagem de: ".$name.".\r\n".$message;

     mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá tenta no lugar de:

```
 $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode("$subject").'?=';
```

use:

```
$subject = "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, quando inclui este código, tudo o que ele fez foi mudar o assunto do e-mail para: Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar dois cabeçalhos abaixo da variável `$headers` para que seu e-mail seja enviado da forma correta.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```